# How to Display the Footnotemark with the Footnotetext within a Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=Gold,text width=0.89\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \textbf{In three words I can sum up everything I've learned about life: ``It goes on.''\footnotemark \vskip 8pt \hfill \emph{---Robert Frost}}
\footnotetext{American poet (1874-1963)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: In the `tikzpicture`, how may I get the footnotemark (in this case, an asterisk) to appear before the footnotetext after the footnoteline?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why, but apparently when splitting the footnote into `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, the `footnote` counter is increased, but the `mpfootnote` counter is used. If you want, you can give the optional `number` like this:

`\footnotemark[number]` and `\footnotetext[number]{text for footnote}`

-Or simply use `\footnote` like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=Gold,text width=0.89\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \textbf{In three words I can sum up everything I've learned about life: ``It goes on.''\footnote{American poet (1874-1963)}
 \vskip 8pt \hfill \emph{---Robert Frost}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled box with text and a footnote]

Comment: Many thanks for this very helpful answer.